# Acceleration as the second derivative of displacement function

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, calculus, displacement

Let $x$ be displacement as a function of time $t$ and some other physical quantity $k$ such that 
$ x = f(t,k) $ 
Now,

1) Will the acceleration $a$ be $\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial t^2}$ or $\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}$ ?

2) Will both of the expressions yield the same result?

Thank You

Comment: What do you exactly mean by some other physical quantity $k$? In classical mechanics, $x$ is to be treated simply as $x(t)$ because there is always a specific position of a particle at each value of time. And any other physical quantity is to be treated as $k(x(t),p(t),t)$ or $k(x(t),\dot{x}(t),t)$.

Comment: My use of $k$ was just to make $x$ an implicit function, I just wanted to know that will $a$ will be defined as the second partial derivative of $x$ wrt $t$ or second derivative of $x$ wrt $t$ ....

Comment: What is your specific application of that?

Comment: consider a situation where x is a function of time and some additional parameter which cannot be differentiated in terms of t, so just differentiating x wrt t will give us (dimensionally speaking) a term of acceleration and another term which will NOT have dimension of acceleration, so i just want to clarify that if we have a function of an implicit function of x, is it correct to use partial derivative ?

Comment: Say in some  problem the x coordinate depends as x = t+y²  taking partial derivative wouldn't  help here  as we don't know time dependence of y

Comment: Also we say mention our position  in space time notice we use both our position as well as time coordinates and then define acceleration as the rate at which the rate of change of position vector changes. If you would like you could introduce other independent variable in the equations of  motion and define a acceleration wrt to it. So yes I would suggest that acceleration is may be defined as a partial derivative only when you could introduce such a independent variable but most of the observables in the physical world are time variate

Comment: You are welcome